# Unknown provider: $translateStaticFilesLoaderProvider <- $translateStaticFilesLoader with yeoman and grunt build

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, angular-translate

I have a simple AngularJS app set up with the [yeoman/generator-angular](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular%20yeoman/generator-angular) generator. For translation services I have installed the following bower packages in the following order:

**bower.json**

```
"angular-translate": "~2.8.1",
"angular-translate-loader-static-files": "~2.8.1",
"angular-translate-handler-log": "~2.8.1"
```

With `grunt wiredep` they get inserted in my main template file next to all the other dependencies:

**app/index.html**

```
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-filter/dist/angular-filter.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-translate-handler-log/angular-translate-handler-log.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

I inject the dependencies in my app like this:

**app/scripts/app.js**

```
var saEvents = angular.module('saEvents', [
'saCore',
'ngSanitize',
'angular.filter',
'ui.router',
'pascalprecht.translate'
]);
```

and configure the `$translateProvider` like this:

```
saEvents

// route configuration via stateProvider
.config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    '$translateProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $translateProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html'
        })
        .state('day', {
            url: '/day/:date',
            controller: 'DayCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'views/days.html',
            resolve: {
                date: ['$stateParams', function ($stateParams) {
                    return $stateParams.date;
                }]
            }
        })
        .state('day.location', {
            url: '/location/:locationId',
            templateUrl: 'views/days.location.html',
            controller: 'LocationCtrl'
        })
        .state('event', {
            url: '/event/:eventId',
            controller: 'EventCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'views/events/detail.html'
        })
    ;

    $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: 'locales/locale-',
        suffix: '.json'
    });
    $translateProvider.useMissingTranslationHandlerLog();
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('de_DE');

}])
```

When I work in development mode with `grunt serve` and open the app at `http://localhost:9000/` everything is working as expected but as soon as I build the project with `grunt build` and open the **dist** version I get the following error:

```
vendor.696ffd4f.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: angular.module(...).run(...) is not a function
vendor.696ffd4f.js:4 Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $translateStaticFilesLoaderProvider <- $translateStaticFilesLoader
```

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/unpr?p0=%24translateStaticFilesLoaderProvider%20%3C-%20%24translateStaticFilesLoader

I managed to get the problem fixed by moving the javascript source files for the angular-translate extension outside of the `<!-- bower:js -->` block:

**app/index.html**

```
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-filter/dist/angular-filter.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
<script src="../bower_components/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-translate-handler-log/angular-translate-handler-log.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/core/core.module.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/core/core.config.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/core/core.services.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/core/core.controller.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

But this feels like a dirty trick and I would be glad for a clean solution.

Comment: Why did you change the file path from "bower_components/" to "../bower_components" when you hard-coded it? That's the first red-flag.

Comment: all the project files reside under the `app` folder, the bower components are on the same level in the `bower_components` folder. To get the sources included when I call `grunt build` I have to use this relative path. 

Another way to solve it was to copy  the code of the two js files into one of the projects source files (e.g. app.js or core.module.js). 

I am pretty new to Angular, yeoman and the whole grunt stuff so I am not sure if this may be related to the grunt setup or the grunt wiredep.